# Filtering one key with the value from another key in jq

Tags: json, string, select, jq

I've got a list of package data in JSON format that looks like:

```
[
  {
    "Package": "pyasn1",
    "Version": "0.4.6",
    "DownloadURL": "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/50/5ce5dbe42eaf016cb9b062caf6d0f38018454756d4feb467de3e29431dae/pyasn1-0.4.6-py2.4.egg"
  },
  {
    "Package": "cachetools",
    "Version": "3.1.1",
    "DownloadURL": "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/6a/abf83cb951617793fd49c98cb9456860f5df66ff89883c8660aa0672d425/cachetools-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl"
  }
]
```

And I'd like to generate a list of items where `.DownloadURL` doesn't contain the string in `.Version`.

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
jq '.[]|select(.DownloadURL | contains(.Version)| not)'
```

I get the following error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:11): Cannot index string with string "Version"
exit status 5
```

I was able to do the following...

```
jq '.[]|select(.DownloadURL | contains("0.4.6")| not)'
```

...and it gave the results I would expect:

```
{
  "Package": "cachetools",
  "Version": "3.1.1",
  "DownloadURL": "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/6a/abf83cb951617793fd49c98cb9456860f5df66ff89883c8660aa0672d425/cachetools-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl"
}
```

Is there a way to use the contents of `.Version` with the `contains()` function or is there a better way to do this?  I've set up [a playground with the data here](https://jqplay.org/s/6oDV3_sMmi).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following has worked for me:

```
jq '.[]|.Version as $v|select(.DownloadURL | contains($v)| not)'
```

```
{
  "Package": "cachetools",
  "Version": "3.1.1",
  "DownloadURL": "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/6a/abf83cb951617793fd49c98cb9456860f5df66ff89883c8660aa0672d425/cachetools-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl"
}
```

Is the result

Comment: Thanks, this did exactly what I wanted, so I'm accepting this answer.  

If you don't mind though could you help me be sure I'm understanding what is happening here?  
From what I see, you're selecting every record coming through the pipeline `select(.)` and the `as $x` is assigning the record to `$x` which then allows me to reference the value of `.Version`. using the `$x.Version`.  Is that about right?

Comment: That's exactly correct, known as `Variable / Symbolic Binding Operator` in the docs (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)

Comment: `jq '.[]|.Version as $v|select(.DownloadURL | contains($v)| not)'` shows the intent more clearer

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to generate a list of items where .DownloadURL doesn't contain the string in .Version.

If as you say you want the result as a list, you could use `map`:

```
map(select( .Version as $v | .DownloadURL | contains($v) | not))
```

However, the semantics of `contains` is very complex so you might wish to consider using `index` instead:

```
map(select( .Version as $v | .DownloadURL | index($v) | not))
```